# Linq join typeddatatable with List and return typeddatatable

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, join, datatable

I hava a strongly typed datatable and a list(of String). 
I want to build a linq query to return a datatable of the same type where the fields of a certain column of the table are in the list. I thought of doing a Join, although in normal sql I would have added

```
SELECT FROM Table WHERE Table.ID IN(...);
```

This is what I tried in linq.

```
Dim Families As List(Of String)
Dim Articles As SomeStronglyTypedDataTable


Dim MatchingArticles = From a In Articles.AsEnumerable _
             Join f In Families.AsEnumerable On a.FamilyCode Equals f.ToString _
             Select New With {}
```

I'm not sure either if I need to convert the query result back to a datatable nor if that's even possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the simpler query:

```
    Dim MatchingArticles = From a In Articles.AsEnumerable _  
                           Where Families.Contains(a.FamilyCode)_  
                           Select a  
    Dim MyMatchingArticlesTable = CopyToDataTable(Of SomeStronglyTypedDataTable) (MatchingArticles)
```

Comment: Thanks, It's what I did in the end but because I needed to return a strongly typed datatable I used merge:

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  Instead of `Select New ...`, select the matching DataRows, `Select a`, and then use [CopyToDataTable(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx) on the matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim table As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable()
        Dim typedtable As New TypedDataset.TypedDataTable
        typedtable.Merge(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was raking my brain trying to get something similar to work, and your code enlightened me.
All I needed was to add the `.AsEnumerable()` on both sides.

I'm working with C#. Anyway, I think all you need to do is select your table like

```
 Dim MatchingArticles = From a In Articles.AsEnumerable _
         Join f In Families.AsEnumerable On a.FamilyCode Equals f.ToString _
         Select a;
```

Well, this is a very old post, but hey, it might help someone else... 
If you think this would resolve your question, please mark it as correct, so others will know. You may also want to mark Devart's answer as correct. I tried it and it works.